# Как обновить pandas dataframe данными из словаря?

Tags: python, pandas, словари

Есть датафрейм:

```
test_dict = {
    'A':1,
    'B':2,
    'C':3,
    'D':None
    }
test_dict_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(test_dict.items())
test_dict_df = test_dict_df.rename(columns={0:'name', 1:'value'})
```

Теперь в этом датафрейме хочу по словарю `update_dict` заменить значение столбца:

```
update_dict = {'D':33}

for i,x in update_dict.items():
    test_dict_df[test_dict_df['name']==i]['value'] = x
```

Но он никак не обновляет таким циклом датафрейм (
хочу именно что-то вроде цикла, потому что в `update_dict` может быть несколько `keys`.

Может, через `apply` как-то можно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
t = test_dict_df["name"].map(update_dict).dropna()
test_dict_df.loc[t.index, "value"] = t
```

результат:

```
In [276]: test_dict_df
Out[276]:
  name  value
0    A    1.0
1    B    2.0
2    C    3.0
3    D   33.0
```

PS метод [Series.map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) заменит все значения ключей на соответствующие им значения, поэтому цикл здесь не нужен.

Comment: магия! спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: @SergeyIlyin, все просто - если в вопросе есть воспроизводимый пример данных, то: 1. такой вопрос гораздо легче понять 2. можно проверить собственный ответ. 3. мотивация дать ответ гораздо выше. PS я пытался вам это объяснить в ваших предыдущих вопросах... ;) Удачи!

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку ваш датафрэйм создается из словаря, а у словаря ключи уникальны, то можно использовать ключи как индекс. Тогда обновлять датафрэйм по словарю можно так:

```
test_dict = {
    'A':1,
    'B':2,
    'C':3,
    'D':None
    }
td = pd.DataFrame(test_dict.items(), columns=['name','value']).set_index('name')

update_dict = {'D':33,'A':44}

td.loc[update_dict,'value'] = pd.Series(update_dict)
```

результат:

```
     value
name      
A       44
B        2
C        3
D       33
```